# How to select conditional createStackNavigator screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to select conditional screen based on Redux data. I have two screens in a screen stack, and this screen stack is also a part of TabNavigator (Logged out screen should be shown with Tabs too). If user is logged in, I need to show **CheckScreen**, otherwise **CheckScreenLoggedOut**. I tried setting `initialRouteName` conditionally but it shows CheckScreenLoggedOut only after logging in.

How can I implement this logic?

Here is my `createStackNavigator` part:

```js
const CheckScreenStack = createStackNavigator(
    {

        CheckSendLoggedOut: {
            screen: IntroScreen,
            navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                headerLeft: (
                    <View>
                        <TestModeIcon/>
                    </View>
                ),
            }),

        },

        CheckScreen: {
            screen: CheckScreen,
            navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                headerRight: (
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity title='' onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('NotificationsScreen'); }}>
                            <NotificationTabBarIcon/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                )
            }),
        },



    },
    {
        initialRouteName: (typeof store.getState().userData !== "undefined") ? 'CheckScreen' : 'CheckSendLoggedOut'
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already achieved this by accessing the redux state with connect, you can do something like this:

```
const CheckScreenStack = ({ userData }) => {
   const Stack = createStackNavigator(
     {
       ...
     },
     {
        initialRouteName: (typeof userData !== "undefined") ? 'CheckScreen' : 'CheckSendLoggedOut'
     }
   );
   return Stack;
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ userData }) => {
  return { userData };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {},
)(CheckScreenStack);
```

Comment: Thank you @Kape but I get "Only one default export allowed per module" error for connect() part. I have also another "export default createStackNavigator" part in my file. How can I implement it?

Comment: here i tried to implement your solution: https://codeshare.io/a3wrZg But I couldn't figure out how to pass Redux data to CheckScreenStack, may you please check CheckScreenStack and MainRootStack parts? I pass MainRootStack to connect()

Comment: then do: export connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {},
)({CheckScreenStack});

Comment: and you'll have to import this: import { connect } from 'react-redux';

Comment: you need to use CheckScreenStack with connect, MainRootStack won't pass the props

Comment: unfortunately for export connect, I get an error. "Declaration or statement expected." on IDE and Unexpected token (419:14) on metro

Comment: and also I declared mapStateToProps, here you can see the recent code: https://codeshare.io/2EDxbw

Comment: you don't need to export connect, try this https://codeshare.io/2EDxbw

Comment: did you remove just export connect part? If I'm not missing anything else, I'm getting "Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it." error and "undefined" userData

Comment: try this import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; return createAppContainer(Stack)

Comment: Oh yeah when I did this I created all navigation stacks inside a single function and then exported returned the root container with createAppContainer and then exported the whole function with export default connect